# AEM 6.1 not showing replicated date and replicated by in publish environment

Tags: aem, jcr

We recently migrated from **CQ 5.5 to AEM 6.1**. In CQ 5.5 when a page is published from author to publish, ***cq:lastReplicated (date when replicated) and cq:lastReplicatedBy (user who replicated)*** used to show on both publish and author **jcr:content** properties.

- Author screenshot:

[image]

- Publish Screenshot:
  [image]

However in AEM 6.1 these two properties show up on Author but not in publish. We do use these properties in our code for specific logic.

Please let me know if these are removed from publish page properties or replaced by some other property? Can it be configured in replication agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AEM 6 onwards cq:lastReplicationAction, cq:lastreplicated and cq:lastReplicatedBy properties are not carried over to publish by design.

In order to carry over these properties disable the below component in author instance:
**com.day.cq.replication.impl.ReplicationPropertiesFilterFactory**